# Prevent sbt from indirectly importing log4j version

Tags: security, sbt, log4j

In my project we are using SBT. We are not directly using log4j but it's being included; probably because one of the libraries we use requires it.

I'm trying to update the code to not use the vulnerable version of log4j but I have no direct control over this import. Is there anything I can do in the build.sbt file to prevent this?

I guess Gradle has some functionality to force this ([step 3 here](https://blog.gradle.org/log4j-vulnerability)). Does SBT have an equivelant?